# Cannot open https sites with Webkit browsers

Tags: macos, google-chrome, webkit

I have tested this using:

- Mac OS X 10.7.2
- Google Chrome 14.0.835.202 Stable w/o any extensions installed
- Google Chrome 16.0.906.0 Canary w/o any extensions installed
- Mail.app 5.1

The error message in Chrome is

`Google Chrome could not load the webpage because <server> took too long to respond. The website may be down, or you may be experiencing issues with your Internet connection.`

I would also have tested Safari, but it crashes on start-up.

I basically can't connect to secure URLs on Webkit browsers. It works in both Opera and Firefox.
Another computer on the same network can connect using Chrome, so it is not a network related issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this by rebooting my computer.